# What is a reliable method to distinguish between different clones during collisions in Scratch?

Tags: collision-detection, race-condition, mit-scratch

I'm working on a game, in which I have a spell system. Different spells deal different amounts of damage to enemies. I need a way for either the enemies, or the spells, to distinguish with which specific entity they are colliding at the moment. For example there may be a fire spell and an ice spell on the screen at the same time, and they both would deal different amounts of damage.

My first solution was using the touching color block. This works fine for a few enemies, the game begins to lag, due to the touching color block having a significant impact on performance. I ended up abandoning this method.

Doing collisions mathematically based on a list of positions and distance will not suffice, because the enemies and spells can be of varying sizes, and it would be a pain to account for that.

My current solution, is to on each frame iterate through all the enemy id's, and hiding all enemies except the one whose id is in the current iteration. I then broadcast another message, which tells the spells to check for any collisions, and if so, add the visible enemy's id, as well as a damage value to a queue. This way there is only one enemy on the screen at a time for the spells to collide with, so I can be certain which one it is. After the itration, I broadcast the update message, and when the enemy clones receive it, they go through the queue and individually apply any damage that is to be dealt if it matches their id. This works great, with one small issue: If the script is ran with screen refreshes, the enemies can be seen disappearing and reappearing, and there is a larger delay between broadcasts, which while not lag itself, makes it appear as though. If the script is ran without screen refresh, nothing seems off, however a race condition arises while iterating, which makes it so that the correct clones are not always visible/hidden, resulting in spells rarely detecting collisions, even though it appears as they should.

Is there a way to fix this? Or perhaps a better way of achieving what I'm trying to do that I haven't thought of?

Comment: You may find one of these Scratch projects useful: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/664601726/ https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/665020766/

Comment: Yes, it might be a pain, but your alternative sounds like lag and hard to sync up

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom block (the pink ones beneath variables) called 'Clone Loop [ID]' with the [ID] being an input. Also, have a variable called 'Clones'. Whenever you create a clone, increment 'Clones' By one, and run 'Clone Loop' with a value of 'Clones' in the ID slot. Now run all your clone's code under the 'Clone Loop'.

You can easily acess each clone by id, you could even create a list of x's and y's so that each clone's ID was the index of it's x and y in these lists. Then, you could easily tell the ID's of the two clones who colided, and if you wanted, you could create a variable 'delete' that when set to the ID of a clone, would delete that clone.

I hope this helps, of it wasn't what you were looking for, please tell me, as I want to make sure you find whatever you need.